# How to apply styles for nth childs inner div?

Tags: html, css

```css
.outer:nth-child(3) > div{
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>1st deep element</div>
  <div>1st deep element</div>
  <div>
    <div>2nd deep element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to control 2nd deep elements style only using outer class selector?

Comment: .outer div:nth-child(3) > div{
   color:red;
}

Comment: The question in your title is different from the question in the post itself. The latter could be answered with simply, `.outer > div > div`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target this way

```
.outer div:nth-child(3)
```

```css
.outer div:nth-child(3) > div{
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>1st deep element</div>
  <div>1st deep element</div>
  <div>
    <div>2nd deep element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
.outer div:nth-child(3)>div:nth-child(1){
   color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are applying [`:nth-child` pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) on the `.outer` class, so separate it by [direct child selector `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

```css
.outer > :nth-child(3) > div{
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>1st deep element</div>
  <div>1st deep element</div>
  <div>
    <div>2nd deep element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I make for you fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/gnfkqj1y/

```css
.outer >div:nth-child(3)  > div{
   color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The div element you want to control is the child of another div element so you should first propagate from parent to child and then select the child there. simple !!@@#

```css
div>div:nth-child(2){
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>1st deep element</div>
  <div>1st deep element</div>
  <div>
    <div>2nd deep element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add a description for author why this works and where he had a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="flowContent">
  <div>
     <div class="rd_1">Container #2</div>
     <div class="rd_2">Container #2</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

If we want to add Style to Nth sub Child without using child classname and using with parent class name

> CSS

```
.wrapper > div:nth-child(1) > div:first-child{
  display: flex
 }
.wrapper > div:nth-child(1) > div:first-child > div:nth-child(1){
  color: red
 }
.wrapper > div:nth-child(1) > div:first-child >div:last-child{
  color: green
 }
```